# "at once" ambiguous between simultanous and immediate

Tags: american-english, ambiguity

I have a statement that uses "at once". It is supposed to mean "in one sweep" but the longer I look at it, the more it sounds to me like "immediately". What would you suggest? Keep it or change it?

> Consider a range of possibilities, where all metadata blocks are
>   either allocated in one continuous range (called an extent), are
>   divided into subsets, or are divided into individual blocks. First
>   approach we shall call the extent approach and it requires that all
>   blocks are read from a continuous area on disk **at once** and after
>   changes are made all blocks are stored to another continuous area **at
>   once**. Last approach we shall call block approach. It is prevalent in
>   modern filesystems. Space is allocated eagerly and non-preemptively,
>   one block at a time eventually leading to fragmentation of metadata.

For comparison, here is a different fragment from same document:

> Consider a hybrid or rather a transitional approach. Initially all
>   entries are loaded from one extent, kept in memory in entirety and the
>   whole time, and occasionally stored to disk as one extent. If at some
>   point amount of entries grows over a certain threshold, a transition
>   to a B-tree representation is commenced, all entries (already in
>   memory) are relocated into tree nodes and stored to disk **in one
>   sweep**. The threshold can be chosen low enough so storing entire
>   dictionary
>   **in one sweep** is faster than analogous B-tree operation (few disk seeks). After transition, operations are carried out on the B-tree
>   representation. If changes are being accumulated over some period of
>   time then comparison is even more favorable. Intents (patches) can be
>   stored to disk to persist individual operations instead of storing the
>   entire dictionary every time. Intents are described in a later chapter
>   on fsync.

Comment: Do you think that using "all at once" instead of just "at once" would adequately remove the ambiguity?

Comment: "in a single read" "in a single write"

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "in one sweep" certainly removes any ambiguity that "at once" might cause, so you're better off standardizing on that.

Comment: To be honest, I do not like "in one sweep". Sweeping is something that should be done to the floor, not the hard disk. That is why I am asking for suggestions. But I do think this is most accurate word suggested so far.

Answer (score 1):

In your context I think it is wiser to be explicit. You need to distinguish between 'simultaneously' and 'immediately'.

*...it requires that all blocks are read from a continuous area on disk **simultaneously**...*

or

*...it requires that all blocks are read from a continuous area on disk **immediately**...*

depending on which you mean.

Comment: Simultaneously is the word I was missing. However, I am not sure it is the best word to use here. Hard disk does not process entire area simultaneously but sequentially, without pause or interleaving with other operations. Kind of a detail really.

Comment: @ArekBulski, yes I had the same thought. I'm doubtful about 'at once' for the same reason. I think you need to say, "at one time"

Comment: "at one time" could also mean unspecified moment, at some point in time? Another ambiguity.